Sunburst, icicle & flame chart in japanese
How do we call in a website, chart type like sunburst, icicle and flame chart in japanese ? do you have some website with the reference of the chart name also in japanese?
I've found :

sunburst: サンバースト
Icicle : つらら but when I search that I don't find my graph (By icicle I mean : https://plotly.com/python/icicle-charts/)
Flame : 炎 but is it not just related to fire things?

For context, we see those name in button to change the look of one graph.
Any idea of the real translation or link that can help me also in the future?

I believe this might be off topic as translation. That said, as far as I can tell, サンバースト and つらら both have at least a small amount of usage. You can search つららチャート (adding "chart" to the end) to get relevant results. For Flame, I'm finding results for フレームグラフ ("Flame Graph" transcribed into katakana, would be フレーム for short). I would caution you that your users are unlikely to be familiar with these very specific visualization types or their names, and are unlikely to be able to make the semantic leap between the names and chart appearances.

I think these are really separate questions that should be dealt with separately; knowing about one chart won't help with understanding the others.

I don't think there are Japanese-specific traditional names for these types of complex charts for hierarchical data. Descriptive explanations would be something like:

階層構造のある円グラフ for sunburst charts
階層構造のある(帯/棒)グラフ for icicle/flame charts. 帯グラフ (≈ stacked bar chart) is chosen when the lengths of the bars are the same, like the one shown in your link

Or you may just use 階層グラフ or 階層チャート to refer to these types of charts in general.
If I need to distinguish them and deal with these types of chart precisely (e.g., when translating the docs for a chart library), I would just transliterate them, possibly after showing the original spellings and/or the literal translations when they first appear, like so:

サンバースト（sunburst; 日光放射）チャート
アイシクル（icicle; つらら）チャート
フレーム（flame; 炎）チャート

But this does not mean laypeople (or even average researchers) instantly understand them.

In fact, it's 3 buttons in the same interface to be able to switch the visualisation of the graph (with same data) in different way. So even in english, I don't really know if a lot of people know the name (except the sunburst one). So I think the 3 last you mentionned with チャート at the end fit the most my problem. Thank you !
